# PHP Form writes blank row to MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm using a simple form to submit a row to my database. I don't get an error connecting to the database and it does inserts the row but it writes all values blank.

This is the form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Título: <input type="text" name="title" />
Privacidad: <select type="text" name="privacy" />
  <option value="public">Publico</option>
  <option value="private">Privado</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is the insert.php file:

```
<?  
    $con = mysql_connect("removed","removed","removed");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

mysql_select_db("copoetry", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy)
VALUES
('$_POST[title]','$_POST[privacy]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You may want to change your database connection details, assuming they were from a live environment. I've removed them from your post in the mean time.

Comment: As I commented on your last question, do `echo $sql` before doing the query to see the problem.

Comment: I used echo $sql and got: INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy) VALUES ('blablabla','public')
However nothing was written to the database, inserting it directly in the index did add the row with the values. But placing it on the insert.php produces a blank row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign $_POST variables instead of trying to inline them into the statement. You will also have to escape whatever quotes may appear inside the POST data. So, do this:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$privacy = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['privacy']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy)
VALUES
('$title','$privacy')";
```

Also, changing stuff to "`'$_POST['title']','$_POST['privacy']'`" won't work at least because to inline array values to a string, you have to use `{}` like `$correct_string = "Hello {$_POST['world']}"`

Answer (score 0):

yes you should change the $_POST[title] and $_POST[privacy] to $_POST['title'] and $_POST['privacy'] .

and also change : `<select type="text" name="privacy" />`

to `<select name="privacy" >`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:
 
`$sql="INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy)
VALUES
('".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['privacy']."')";`


or:
 `$sql="INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy)
VALUES
('{$_POST['title']}','{$_POST['privacy']}')";`

should work, your problem is coming from the quotation marks. Find a way to get around them and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the GLARING PROBLEM of SQL injection / badly formed SQL, this should work as long as the values don't contain any single quotes.

Try writing $sql and var_export($_POST,true) to your log file for each operation to see what's actually happening.